# Prevent AVAudioPlayers from playing simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm having a UITableView with a few cells and every cell has a button which triggers an `AVAudioPlayer` that is created in the subclassed cell. Every cell stands for a person and with a tap on the button their audio file is played.

Now, when I tap on the first row it plays like it should. But when I tap on the second row (while the first one is still playing) it plays both of them, obviously. I want to stop the first row if it is playing.

I tried to create a property of `YBCell` in my view controller and if a row plays the sound, it stops the other cells from playing and assigns itself to the property. This way the first time it will be `nil`.

YBCell.m

```
- (IBAction)playOrStop:(id)sender
{
    if (thisCellIsPlaying)
    {
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
        thisCellIsPlaying = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        YBViewController *vc = [[YBViewController alloc] init];
        [vc stopOtherCellPlaying];

        [self.audioPlayer play];
        [vc setPlayingCell:self];

        thisCellIsPlaying = TRUE;
    }
}
```

YBViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) YBCell *playingCell;
- (void)stopPlaying;
```

YBViewController.m

```
- (void) stopPlaying
{
    [self.playingCell.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Problem is that when I check `self.playingCell` in `-(void) stopPlaying` it always returns `nil`. Also instead of the whole cell, using a tag for every cell with `indexPath.row` doesn't work since it always returns 0.

If there is not a straight answer I will probably try to create one audio player in the view controller and let the cells share it, though I figured it would be better to let every cell have its own player.

Comment: ya it is better to create player in view controller...

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you are creating new Object **YBCell** and playing the song from **YBViewController** through the object(AVaudioPlayer).Declare your **AVaudioplayer** in **app delegate** and Access it from Both **YBCell** & **YBViewController**